# update row in mysql table in jsp

Tags: mysql, forms, jsp, sql-update

i´m trying to update rows in `mysql table`, i´m using `html form` for data insertion. In html form attribute `value` i´m using an existing data from database.

Edit.jsp

```
<form action="Update.jsp">
                <%  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
                    Statement st = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select u.login,i.name,i.surname,i.age,i.tel,i.email,a.street,a.town,a.zip,ul.name,t.name from users u join info i on i.user_id=u.user_id join user_level ul on ul.ulevel=u.ulevel join teams t on t.team_id=u.team_id join adress a on a.info_id=i.info_id where u.login='" + session.getAttribute("uzivatel") + "'");
                    while (rs.next()) {
                %>

                <div class="well well-large">
                    <font size="2"><b>Welcome, </b></font><font color="RED"><i><%= session.getAttribute("uzivatel")%></i></font><br>
                    <b>Name:</b> <input type="text" name="name" value="<%= rs.getString(2)%>"><input type="text" name="surname" value="<%= rs.getString(3)%>"> <br>
                    <b>Age:</b> <input type="text" name="age" value="<%= rs.getString(4)%>"><br>
                    <b>Telephone:</b> <input type="text" name="tel" value="0<%= rs.getString(5)%>"><br>
                    <b>E-mail:</b> <input type="text" name="email" value="<%= rs.getString(6)%>"><br>
                    <b>Adress:</b> <input type="text" name="street" value="<%= rs.getString(7)%>"><input type="text" name="town" value="<%= rs.getString(8)%>"><input type="text" name="zip" value="<%= rs.getString(9)%>"><br>
                    <b>User level:</b> <%= rs.getString(10)%><br>
                    <b>Team:</b> <%= rs.getString(11)%><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Update.jsp

```
<%
                String name = request.getParameter("name");
                String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
                String age = request.getParameter("age");
                String telephone = request.getParameter("tel");
                String email = request.getParameter("email");
                String street = request.getParameter("street");
                String town = request.getParameter("town");
                String zip = request.getParameter("zip");

                try {
                    Connection conn = null;
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
                    Statement st1 = null;
                    st1 = conn.createStatement();
                    System.out.println(session.getAttribute("uzivatel"));
                    st1.executeUpdate("UPDATE users JOIN info ON users.user_id = info.user_id"
                            + " JOIN adress ON info.info_id = adress.info_id"
                            + "SET info.name = '"+name+"',info.surname = '"+surname+"',"
                            + "info.age = '"+age+"',info.tel = '"+telephone+"',info.email = '"+email+"',"
                            + "adress.street = '"+street+"',adress.town = '"+town+"',adress.zip = '"+zip+"',"
                            + "WHERE users.login ='" + session.getAttribute("uzivatel") + "'  ");
                    response.sendRedirect("AdministrationControlPanel.jsp");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            %>
```

When I pressed the Submit button, it redirected me to `Update.jsp` and nothing was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in your query that is why you are not getting any result. give space at properly when you are dividing the string in various lines.
system.out.println() will show message on the console not on the page

```
st1.executeUpdate("UPDATE users JOIN info ON users.user_id = info.user_id"
                        + " JOIN adress ON info.info_id = adress.info_id "
                        + "SET info.name = '"+name+"',info.surname = '"+surname+"', "
                        + "info.age = '"+age+"', info.tel = '"+telephone+"', info.email = '"+email+"',"
                        + "adress.street = '"+street+"',adress.town = '"+town+"',adress.zip = '"+zip+"', "
                        + "WHERE users.login ='" + session.getAttribute("uzivatel") + "'  ");
```

Comment: I change it. Now the output shows:
Syntax error or access violation, message from server: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE users.login ='admin'' at line 1"

Comment: I found the mistake: there was a comma before the WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Better you use jQuery rather than calling page update.jsp. When you use jQuery that time you can send data to update.jsp page with parameter and take response from that page and print it in you page even you can take all table data from the jQuery

It is very simple Hope this will help you.. for sample example have look of following urls

demo
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/jquery/jqDatabaseConnect.html

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/